# how to do a mongoexport in nodejs for collection in mongodb atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoexport

In my node.js app I use mongoexport to export the data to json format with the following running perfectly fine.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
ls = spawn('mongoexport',['--db', 'mydatabase','--collection', 'mycollection', '--out', 'output.json']);
```

but then it has not been working since I moved the data to the mongodb compass atlas. I tried to change the database to test, it does not work. Note that I have a mongoose.connect to atlas, the connection works, as I can save data to the collection.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
ls = spawn('mongoexport',['--db', 'test','--collection', 'mycollection', '--out', 'output.json']);
```

then I tried the following and it still does not work

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
ls = spawn('mongoexport',['--uri', 'mongodb+srv://myname:mypassword@cluster0v1prw.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority','--collection', 'mycollection', '--out', 'output.json']);
```

Is there other option I can do to export the data to a json file using node.js?
TIA.

Comment: are you able to export data from CLI?

Comment: No. I used mongoexport --host cluster0-v1prw.mongodb.net --db  ... I got "could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: cluster0-v1prw.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp: lookup cluster0-v1prw.mongodb.net: no such host }, ] }" seems that it is physical name of a virtual host as I can't ping the host

Comment: what about the rest of the queries? Are you able to fetch data with curd queries?

Comment: I am surprised, I was able to get a few lines of data. I thought I would not get anything, as it did not host is unknown (as I confirmed with ping), but then it only represented about 1/10 of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass in the whole parameter for mongoexport.

```js
//Dependencies
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const exportParams =
    `mongoexport --host uriz:27017,uriy:27017,urlx:27017 --ssl --username <userName> --password <password> --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbName --collection collectionName--type json --fields --out fileName.json `


//Define the spawn function
const childSpawn = () => {
    //Get the export parameters

    // MongoDB dump child process
    const mongoDump = exec(exportParams, (error, stdout, stderr) => {

        if (error) {
            console.log(error.stack);
            console.log('Child MONGO Error code: ' + error.code);
            console.log('Child MONGO Signal received: ' + error.signal);
        }
        console.log('Child MONGO Process STDOUT: ' + stdout);
        console.log('Child MONGO Process STDERR: ' + stderr);
    });

    mongoDump.on('exit', (code) => {
        console.log('MONGO Child process exited with exit code ' + code);
    });
};

module.exports = { childSpawn }
```

Comment: thanks But still does not work, I tried the command line and still got 2020-04-22T21:32:47.055-0400    could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: cluster0-shard-00-02-v1prw.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : connection(cluster0-shard-00-02-v1prw.mongodb.net:27017[-168]) incomplete read of message header: EOF }, { Addr: cluster0-shard-00-01-v1prw.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : ...

Comment: Check the Atlas network access. Did you allow connection from your IP?